# how to create directX dxtrans.lib

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, directx, winapi

How can I build dxtrans.lib using VisualStudio 2010 on Windows-7 32-bit?

I've downloaded and installed DirectX, but can't find 
dxtrans.lib and can't find a project to build it.

I need it for a VisualStudio 2010 project that was originally a project in VisualStudio 2005, but when I convert and build it with VS2010, I get error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'dxtrans.lib'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is obsolete as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This topic documents a feature of Visual Filters and Transitions,
>   which is deprecated as of Windows Internet Explorer 9 and obsolete as
>   of Internet Explorer 10.

So, you don't find it in recent SDKs.

But if you still feel that you need it, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx) you can find how to get it (Chuck Walbourn always helps =) ) :

> The August 2007 DirectX SDK was the last version to include dxtrans.h
>   and dxtrans.lib. This technology was used at one point by Internet
>   Explorer, but this is no longer in use.

So, now you want to look at MS downloads website to find this version. But, the problem that there is no such version. The only I could find is [DirectX SDK - (April 2006)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24982). But you can dig a serch engine and probably find something better.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Solution is do just delete dxtrans.lib from list of libs in project's linker properties.

Comment: Well, a good solution. Don't forget to delete all code that using it (if any) =)